# Merging RTF Files With Cocoa

Tags: macos, cocoa, merge, rtf

How would one do this? I know just merging NSData doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Playing with NSAttributedString should work, something like the code shown below

This is a very quick and dirty way to merge many RTF files together

```
- (void)mergeRTF:(NSURL*)rtf1 :(NSURL*)rtf2 :(NSURL*)merged {
    NSMutableDictionary *options = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    [options setObject:[NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInteger:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
                forKey:NSCharacterEncodingDocumentOption];
    NSDictionary *docAttrs = nil;
    NSError* error = nil;

    NSAttributedString *rtfText1 = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithURL:rtf1
                                                               options:options
                                                    documentAttributes:&docAttrs
                                                                 error:&error];

    NSAttributedString *rtfText2 = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithURL:rtf2
                                                                options:options
                                                     documentAttributes:&docAttrs
                                                                  error:&error];
    NSMutableAttributedString* whole = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithAttributedString:rtfText1];
    [whole appendAttributedString:rtfText2];
    NSData* data = [whole RTFFromRange:NSMakeRange(0, whole.length) documentAttributes:nil];

    [data writeToURL:merged atomically:YES];
}
```